# how can I specify the linear programming I have created to be maximizing or minimizing programming with lpsolve

Tags: python, lpsolve

I am learning to use lpsolve in python to solve the linear programming, I followed the [website](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), and it worked well. But I could not find where to set the max/min attribute in LP problem, it has tortured me for some days.

Answer (score 2):

taking a quick look, it seem to me you need to use `set_maxim` and `set_minim`, as in [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/set_maxim.htm). from python code it would be:

```
lpsolve('set_maxim', lp)
```

or

```
lpsolve('set_minim', lp)
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what exactly I want.